# Delete the 'box-sizing: border-box' property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to remove the box-sizing property, I do not want to set it to its default value (content-box). I have this:

```
.glyphicon-menu-up:before {
content: "\e260"; }

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

*:before,
*:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box; }

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }
```

When I am on Google Chrome and I uncheck the box, everything is aligned and as I want :

```
*, :after, :before {
   /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
```

But when I delete the line on my program, it does not change anything, my elements are not aligned.

HTML :

```
<app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.3.3"><div _ngcontent-c0="">
                <list-container _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1=""><div _ngcontent-c1="" class="row row-reduced" id="chat-threads">
                        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="conversation-top-bar-container">
                            <h3 _ngcontent-c1="" class="top-bar-title">
                                Messagerie
                                <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="top-bar-unread-message" title="5 messages non-lus">
    5
  </span>
                            </h3>

                            <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="top-bar-btn" id="top-bar-btn">
                                <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="top-bar-btn create" title="Créer une nouvelle discussion">

                                    <i _ngcontent-c1="" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                                </button>

                                <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="top-bar-btn settings" title="Réglages">
                                    <i _ngcontent-c1="" class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                                </button>

                                <div _ngcontent-c1="" id="outside"></div>

                                <button _ngcontent-c1="" class="top-bar-btn reduce" title="Réduire la liste">
                                    <i _ngcontent-c1="" class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="settings-notification" id="settings-notification">
                            <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="tr triangle">
                                <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="tr inner-triangle">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="sound-signal">
                                Signal sonore :
                                <input _ngcontent-c1="" checked="checked" id="soundsignal1" name="soundsignal" type="radio">
                                <label _ngcontent-c1="" for="soundsignal1">Oui</label>
                                <input _ngcontent-c1="" id="soundsignal2" name="soundsignal" type="radio">
                                <label _ngcontent-c1="" for="soundsignal2">Non</label>
                            </div>

                            <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="flash-signal">
                                Signal visuel :
                                <input _ngcontent-c1="" checked="checked" id="flashsignal1" name="flashsignal" type="radio">
                                <label _ngcontent-c1="" for="flashsignal1">Oui</label>
                                <input _ngcontent-c1="" id="flashsignal2" name="flashsignal" type="radio">
                                <label _ngcontent-c1="" for="flashsignal2">Non</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div _ngcontent-c1="" class="conversation-wrap">
                            <list-item _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c3=""><div _ngcontent-c3="" class="media conversation">
                                    <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="pull-left">

                                        <!----><div _ngcontent-c3="" class="logo-participants-title">
                                            <!----><div _ngcontent-c3="" class="logo-nottalk">
                                                FP
                                            </div>

                                            <!---->
                                        </div>

                                        <!---->

                                        <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="media-body">
                                            <div _ngcontent-c3="" class="message-unread">

                                                <!----><div _ngcontent-c3="" class="media-participants-title">
                                                    <!----><h5 _ngcontent-c3="" class="media-heading contact-name">
                                                        Flofloflo Peron
                                                    </h5>

                                                    <!---->

                                                    <!---->
                                                </div>

                                                <!---->

                                                <!----><small _ngcontent-c3="" class="message-preview">
                                                    RERE</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <a _ngcontent-c3="" class="div-link">Select</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </list-item>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </list-container>
            </div>
```

Comment: The problem would become a lot clearer if you also include the corresponding HTML code.

Comment: box-sizing cannot be simply "removed". It has a default value of "content-box". If removing it from your developer tool does not produce the same as removing it from your code, it means there is another rule affecting it somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe there is another stylesheet that applies this style. I also think you would have to include the corresponding HTML code.

Comment: Yes I have implemented my project in another project. And since then, nothing is aligned.

Comment: @Floriane why don't you add `initial` instead of removing it.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo
Because when I put `initial`, everything is not aligned

Comment: @Floriane to get better understanding can you pls put your code in fiddler and share.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of box-sizing is content-box so if you want box-sizing value to be border-box you have to explicitly assign it. 
The reason it's working when you uncheck

```
*, :after, :before {
   /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
```

because in browser it will pick the previous line which is also defined border-box

```
*:before,
*:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: So if I understood correctly, I can not remove the box-sizing property?
Because when I give it any property (initial, border-box ...) this is not aligned.

Comment: yes you cannot remove it, if you remove it, it's default value will be assigned which is content-box, and I guess content-box is breaking your design. So assign border-box.